# The range and domain of $o(x)=3+\sqrt{16-(x-3)^2}$

Tags: functions

What is the domain and range of $$o(x)=3+\sqrt{16-(x-3)^2}\tag1$$

---

For the **domain**, I know that the expression under the radical has to be larger than or equal to $0$. So therefore, I get this:$$16-(x-3)^2\geq 0\\(7-x)(x+1)\geq 0\\\therefore x\in [-1,7]$$
But for the **range**, I thought of the function as a square root function; because it is in the form $y=\sqrt x+b$. Since the square root of something cannot be less than $0$, I thought the range was $[3,+\infty)$. Which is wrong (according to the book).

The range is supposedly $[3,7]$.

Comment: $0$ is clearly the minimum nonnegative value of $16-(x-3)^2$.  What about the maximum value?

Comment: Note the discrininant, $16 -(x-3)^2\le 16$ and never higher.  So $o (x) \le 7s never more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
-1 \leq x \leq 7 \Leftrightarrow \\ \\ -4 \leq x-3 \leq 4 \Rightarrow \\ \\ 0 \leq (x-3)^2 \leq 16 \Leftrightarrow \\ \\ -16 \leq -(x-3)^2 \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow \\ \\ 
0 \leq 16-(x-3)^2 \leq 16 \Leftrightarrow \\ \\ 
0 \leq \sqrt{16-(x-3)^2} \leq 4 \Leftrightarrow \\ \\
3 \leq 3+\sqrt{16-(x-3)^2} \leq 7
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are right that $\sqrt{x}+b $ can not be less than $b $ so $3 +\sqrt {16- (x-3)^2} $ can't be less than $3$.

But note: $\sqrt {a - x} $ can not ever be *more* than $\sqrt {a} $.  So $b \le b +\sqrt {x -a} \le b + \sqrt a$.

So $16 - (x-3)^2 \le 16$ so $0 \le \sqrt {16 - (x-3)^2}\le 4$ so $3 \le 3+\sqrt {16 - (x-3)^2}\le 7$ so